# Load new form in background worker and showdialog in completed method

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to load new form in background and show it after loaded.
but I always got this error : "invalid cross-thread access" with the code under:
How to make it work?!

```
public partial class f1 : Form
{
    private Form f2;
    public f1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
        bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(dowork);
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(completed);
    }
    void dowork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        f2 = new f2();
    }

   void completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        f2.showdialog();
        this.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: It will never work. You cannot do any UI work on a background thread. What would you gain anyway in this specific scenario? If you have long running work in the constructor move that code away and maybe you can offload (parts of that) method to a background thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid cross thread access backgroundworker error c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597958/invalid-cross-thread-access-backgroundworker-error-c-sharp)

Comment: Wrong approach. You should immediately show `f2` (by the way, it is a **very bad class name** as it is meaningless and does not even follow standard naming convention). And once the form is shown then you start background processing from that new form. If you don't want to immediately display the new form, then you should provide some feedback to the user so that he know that something happen.

Answer (score 1):

you may have to separate the data loading for form and form UI initialization into two different faze.

I have changed your code sample to the following.

```
  public partial class Form2 : Form
        {
            public Form2()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
                bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
                bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(dowork);
                bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(completed);
            }
            void dowork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {    
                e.Result = InitializeNeededDataToShowOnTheSecondform();
            }


            void completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                {
                    var f2 = new Form3(e.Result);
                    f2.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();

                }));
            }

            private object InitializeNeededDataToShowOnTheSeconDform()
            {
//time consuming data initialization and/or any other time consuming process
                return 10;
            }

        }
```